# Open .data file in R

Tags: r

I download and .data from the UCI page.

I don´t know how to open the data set in R. I have tried with the function open(), but it doesn´t works.

Pls how can I open de file in R

Comment: I don't know. The file ending doesn't tell us how the file was created. Maybe `help("load")`?

Comment: `.data` isn’t a well-known, established file extension for a specific format. And UCI isn’t a widely-known, unambiguous abbreviation. You need to provide more information about your data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, these are just textfiles. You can read it in via `read.table` or something similar. You can also have a look at the file in a normal text-editor to see the structure and then read it in according to the structure.